# What's the humor in this Neil DeGrasse Tyson joke? "What Flat-Earthers fear most is sphere itself"

Tags: phrase-meaning

The scientist Neil DeGrasse Tyson posted this joke recently

> What Flat-Earthers fear most is sphere itself

Can someone explain that? This is beyond my understanding…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 1933 the new President Franklin D. Roosevelt made a speech in which he said

> The only thing we have to fear is fear itself

It is a very famous phrase.

This is a pun, replacing "fear" with the rhyming word "sphere".  Which is relevant because "flat-Earthers" believe that the Earth is *not* a sphere.

Comment: You could make lots of jokes like this "What teetotalers fear most is beer itself".  "What a student fears most is career itself" etc.

Comment: Ahaha… brilliant, thanks